# Apply cart price rule to cart programmatically without a coupon code

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, quote

This is my code to add some products to cart(quote):

```
foreach ($params as $param) {
   $product = $this->productRepository->getById($param['product']);
   $this->cart->addProduct($product, $param);
}
```

The `$param` variable looks like:

```
   'product' => //id of the product
   'qty' => 1
```

I found this : [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12893/how-to-apply-all-valid-shopping-cart-price-rules-to-quote), but it is about having a coupon code. I don't have any. Also, which columns from  `quotes` table represents the total with the cart price rule applied ?

Comment: why don't ypu create shopping cart rule without coupon code, once your cart matches the cart rule conditions magento automatically apply that rule.

Comment: @RanjitShinde , I thought i need to add it manually. I didn't know that it is automatically.  And where can i see that ? in the database ? the total amount applied and the final total ?

Comment: No we don't need to add it manually. You can see that in magento admin->Marketing -> Promotions -> Cart Price Rules

Comment: I mean the total amount with the rule applied in the quote columns. For some reason i cannot find it. there are too many totals

Comment: table `quote` and `grand_total` is the final total. You can check `applied_rule_ids` in the quote as well as quote_item table